# how to make an enemy only attack the player when the player is in a state that can be attacked?

Tags: 2d, topdown

how to make an enemy only attack the player when the player is in a state that can be attacked in unity C#

Comment: What do you mean by `when the player is in a state that can be attacked` ?

Comment: like in normal state the enemy cannot attack the player

Comment: Do you mean animation state ?